# Morph existing QTcpSocket to QSslSocket

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qsslsocket

Is it possible to create a new QSslSocket and for it to take ownership over the existing TCP connection, and the old QTcpSocket to be discarded, without interrupting or closing the TCP connection?

I need this to implement explicit FTPS in my FTP server, which requires that initially the connection is unencrypted, and only upon the FTP client's request (the command `AUTH SSL` or `AUTH TLS`), if it comes at all, an SSL/TLS handshake is initiated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is possible. The simplest way to do this is to replace the `QTcpSocket` with a `QSslSocket`. The `QSslSocket` will behave exactly like a normal `QTcpSocket` (no encryption) until you call `startClientEncryption`. After that the `QSslSocket` will act like a normal `QTcpSocket` but all communication is encrypted in the background.

Using this I was actually able to port a 100k+ lines project to use SSL in less than one hour.

## Edit

There is no (real) overhead to use `QSslSocket` in unencrypted mode since it will just call the corresponding `QTcpSocket` method. For example the read method (`qsslsocket.cpp` Qt 4.8.3):

```
if (d->mode == UnencryptedMode && !d->autoStartHandshake) {
    readBytes = d->plainSocket->read(data, maxlen);
} else {
//encryption stuff
```